# How to change/replace url in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices, content-management-system, blogs

I want to show some post based category inside on postid. When I fire this url http://localhost:8081/CMS/Java/4  ---I Got desire output But I dont want show postid in url ..I want show this url http://localhost:8081/CMS/Java/what-is-java  ..

Can someone please me for the same..

Show url--`http://localhost:8081/CMS/Java/what-is-java instead of http://localhost:8081/CMS/Java/4`

```
<c:forEach items="${ postByCategoryAndPostId}" var="menus">

<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/${category}/${menus.postId}"class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">${menus.title} </a>

</c:forEach>






@GetMapping({"{catName}/{postId}"})
    public String showPostByCategoryAndId(@PathVariable("catName")String catName ,@PathVariable("postId") int postId ,Model model)
    {
        
    Optional<Post> post = postServices.getPostByCategoryIdAndPostId(catName,postId);
    Category category = categoryServices.getCategoryByName(catName);
    
    if(post.isPresent()){
            model.addAttribute("content",post.get().getContents());
            model.addAttribute("title",post.get().getTitle());
            model.addAttribute("updateDate",post.get().getUpdatedAt());
            model.addAttribute("category", category.getCatName());
            model.addAttribute("postByCategoryAndPostId", category.getPostId());
            
        }
        //model.addAttribute("category", category.getCatName());
        
    
    else
    {
        model.addAttribute("postNotFoundByCategory","There is no post relate to this Category");
    }
    
        
        return "content/home";
```

Show url--http://localhost:8081/CMS/Java/what-is-java instead of http://localhost:8081/CMS/Java/4

Comment: `/4` is the value of `/${menu.postId}`. In `/${menu.postId}` you need to change `postId` to the field that contains `what-is-java`

Comment: I have already used like this /${menu.postId}

Comment: Does `/$menu.postId}` field contain values like "what-is-java"?

Comment: Yes i want to as a string instead of int